# Vue Component Communication (Parent > Children)

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component (todo-list) with a child component inside (todo-item). I am trying to create a checkbox(check all todos) in the parent so that when all todos will be checked with one click.

With the checkAll() in the parent component, it change the props of the child but it does not change the data of the child.

[image]

This is the parent component todo-list

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-list-container">
    <todo-input @addTodo="addTodo"></todo-input>
    <todo-item v-for="(todo, index) in todos" 
      :key="todo.id" 
      :todo="todo" 
      :index="index" 
      :completed="todo.completed"
      @removeTodo="removeTodo"
      @changedCompleted="changedCompleted"
    ></todo-item>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="button-aux-div"></div>
      <a href="#" class="todo-button">
        <input type="checkbox" :checked="!anyRemaining" @change="checkAll">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Vue from 'vue'
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'
import TodoInput from './TodoInput'

export default {
  name: 'todo-list',

  components: {
    TodoItem,
    TodoInput,
  },

  data () {
    return {
      idForTodo: 3,
      todos: [
        {
          'id': '1',
          'title': 'title1',
          'body': 'body1',
          'completed': false,
        },
        {
          'id': '2',
          'title': 'title2',
          'body': 'body2',
          'completed': false,
        },
      ],
      allChecked: false,
    }
  },

  computed: {
    remaining() {
      return this.todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed).length
    },
    anyRemaining() {
      return this.remaining != 0
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addTodo(todoMessage) {
      this.todos.push({
        id: this.idForTodo,
        title: 'title' + this.idForTodo,
        body: todoMessage,
        completed: false,
      })

      this.idForTodo++;
    },

    removeTodo(data) {
      this.todos.splice(data.index, 1);
      this.idForTodo--;
    },

    changedCompleted(data) {
      this.todos.splice(data.index, 1, data.todo)
    },

    checkAll() {
      this.todos.forEach((todo) => todo.completed = event.target.checked)
    },
  },

}
</script>
```

This is the child componenet todo-item

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-item-container">
    <div class="todo-title-container">
      <div class="todo-id-container">
        <div id="todo-id">
          <h2>{{ id }}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="todo-title"><h2>{{ title }}</h2></div>
      <div class="todo-completed-container">
        <a href="#" class="todo-button">
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="completed" @change="changedCompleted">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="todo-delete-container">
        <a href="#" class="todo-button" @click="deletedTodo">×</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="todo-body-container">
      <p id="todo-body">{{ body }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TodoItem',

  props: {
    todo : {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    index : {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data () {
    return {
      'id': this.todo.id,
      'title': this.todo.title,
      'body': this.todo.body,
      'completed': this.todo.completed,
    }
  },  

  methods: {

    deletedTodo() {
      this.$emit('removeTodo', {
        'index': this.index,
        'todo': {
          'id': this.id,
          'title': this.title,
          'body': this.body,
          'completed': this.completed,
        }
      })
    },

    changedCompleted() {
      this.$emit('changedCompleted', {
        'index': this.index,
        'todo': {
          'id': this.id,
          'title': this.title,
          'body': this.body,
          'completed': this.completed,
        }
      })
    },
  },
}

</script>
```

Comment: I am not seeing - `completed` prop get received by `child-component`

Comment: below @subhasis suggested to add a computed property. But do I need to pass the completed prop from my parent to child? As it has already been included in the todo item.

Comment: `props` are reactive, you don't need to put it into `computed`. It's probably not working here cuz `object` are reference values and you are passing a address of the object so any update inside need to get deeply watched.Now -  if you pass  `completed` prop to `child` and whenever  `completed` get updated `child` will get the updated value.

Comment: when i passed the completed prop to the child component, yes it update the prop as well as the data 'completed' in the child component. But still, when I try to checkall, the prop changes in the parent component but it does not change the data 'completed' in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'completed': this.todo.completed,` . 
Use

```
computed: {
  completed () {
    return this.todo.completed
  }
}
```

Comment: does that mean data in component is not reactive and I need to always put my prop under computed?

Comment: No, the data is component is reactive. But if you are instantiating data fields from prop it will not be reactive i.e. updating prop will not update the data field reactively.

Comment: tried that out but received the error message: "Computed property "completed" was assigned to but it has no setter." Is this because that I have a v-model on my checkbox to the computed property?

Comment: You received that error because - you are receiving a `prop` name - `completed` and also making `computed` property with the same name